# How to generate .xml file in coldfusion?

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I am invoking a ColdFusion webservice through cfinvoke

```
<cfinvoke
   method="getUsers"
   returnvariable="rawXMLUserList"
   webservice="http://www.xyz.com/getusers.cfc?wsdl"
>
  <cfinvokeargument name="userid" value="123">
</cfinvoke>
```

And I am storing XML returnvariable into `userList` variable

```
<cfset userList = XmlParse(rawXMLUserLis)>
```

Now I have to generate output in XML format so that I can save this document in **abc.xml**.

How to save this content into **.xml**?

Comment: You've a typo in your XmlParse() call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save it

```
 <cffile action="write" output=#userlist# file="#ExpandPath('abc.xml')#">
```

To display it raw:

```
<cfoutput>#userList#</cfoutput>
```

To display it safely on a web page:

```
<cfoutput>#xmlFormat(userList)#</cfoutput>
```

To display it formatted

```
<cfdump var=#userList#/>
```

To make downloadable

```
<cfinvoke
   method="getUsers"
   returnvariable="rawXMLUserList"
   webservice="http://localhost/getusers.cfc?wsdl">
  <cfinvokeargument name="userid" value="123">
</cfinvoke>

<cfsavecontent variable="userList">
    <cfoutput>#XmlParse(rawXMLUserList)#</cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>

<cfcontent  type="text/plain" reset="true"  />
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=abc.xml" />
<cfoutput>#userList#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to save this abc.xml in user's pc, using cffile it is saving on server pc, i have to save it on user's pc who is calling this method.

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as that ;)

```
     <cfset data = { 'a' = 1, 'b' = 2, 'c' = 3 } />       
     <cfset var xmloutput = rereplacenocase( serializeXML(data) , '&(?!##?[a-z0-9]+;)', '&amp;', 'all') />

     <cfheader name="Content-type" value="text/xml" charset="utf-8"> 
     <cfoutput>#xmloutput#</cfoutput>
```